# How to filter data by two clauses in Elasticsearch?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, filtering, kibana, non-relational-database

I am trying to filter a data set based on two conditions. I want my results to return the record if it satisfies either the condition 1 (where record contains A and B), or condition 2 (where record contains A and C), with wildcards included.

For example, if I have this table here (and Z is just a random filler character):

```
TABLE 1
AZZZ ZBZ
ZZZZ ZAZ
ZZAZ ZZB
CZZZ ZZA
AZZZ ZCZ
ZZZZ ZZZ
ZZCZ ZZZ
```

I would want my return result to be this:

```
TABLE 1 (Returned)
AZZZ ZBZ
ZZAZ ZZB
CZZZ ZZA
AZZZ ZCZ
```

I've been trying codes along these lines, but can not seem to get the desired results:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "query_string":{  
         "analyze_wildcard":true,
         "default filter":"*",
         "query":"A B"
      }
   }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Wildcard queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) allow you to match parts of a string on not analyzed (`keyword`) fields, for example:

   ```
   POST my_index/_search
   {
       "query": {
           "wildcard" : { "my_field" : "*A*" }
       }
   }
   ```
2. [Bool queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) are your friend for combining things. I think it would be easier to restructure this to the following which should be equivalent:

   ```
   POST my_index/_search
   {
     "query": {
       "bool" : {
         "must" : {
           "wildcard" : { "my_field" : "*A*" }
         },
         "should" : [
           { "wildcard" : { "my_field" : "*B*" } },
           { "wildcard" : { "my_field" : "*C*" } }
         ],
         "minimum_should_match" : 1
       }
     }
   }
   ```

But this won't be very performant. It's a bit hard to abstract what kind of data you have there and what you want to achieve, but maybe there is a better way to achieve that? The problem feels very much modelled around the features of relational databases whereas a search engine has a lot more options.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you very much. You have a good intuition, the problem is modeled around a relational database, because we modeled this whole project on a relational database but got hit with a non relational database two months in, and no one (me included) has any experience with these databases. 

I'm still trying to translate our analysis plan/sql searches to non-relational database/Elasticsearch and are having some trouble doing so. 

Would the guides on the elastic.co websites be the best in learning elasticsearch, or are there other good learning tools to look into?

Comment: The [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html) are good and quite extensive. If you want a condensed version there are also the [official trainings](https://www.elastic.co/training/) especially Engineering I and II for your use case. Disclaimer: I work for Elastic and occasionally give the trainings as well.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give the documents a look through.